# How can I send mail from my app with underline or bold text?

Tags: android, email

My code:

```
String html = "<html><body><b<bold</b><u>underline</u></body></html>";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, Uri.parse("mailto:"));
intent.setType("text/html");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
Html.fromHtml(html));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
```

The result is normal text. Is there a way to make this text bold and underline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the type `text/html` with `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` according to [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND). Have you tried with `EXTRA_STREAM`?

On the other hand, you have a HTML sintax error in the bold tag:

```
String html = "<html><body><b<bold</b><u>underline</u></body></html>";
```

should be:

```
String html = "<html><body><b>bold</b><u>underline</u></body></html>";
```

**UPDATE:**

It may be a bug in your default email app, have a go with the Gmail app if you can and see what happens. Change the code a bit to choose again your default mail client:

```
try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail"));
    Log.i("MAIL", "Finished sending email");
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
    "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

As you can see in the picture below, it works with the default Mail app of the Android framework.

[image]

Have you tried for example with the Project Build Target to 4.3?

[image]

Comment: Doesn't matter, result is the same. Just a typo when prescribing. Did it worked for you?

Comment: I need more info: What app are you using to perform the ACTION_SEND intent? and what Android API level are you using?

Comment: Sorry for not responding so long. I missed stackoverflow notification. I tried to use EXTRA_STREAM with no luck. Is this my API level: minSdkVersion="8" targetSdkVersion="17"? How can I check what app is started to perform email send? I think that it is using default mail app.

Comment: P.S. Whene I use EXTRA_STREAM content of email is empty.

Comment: But I have email client installed and I think it is Gmail app because what else could it be on emulator?

Comment: 4.3 is much to high for my client, it have to work on phones with android 2.3.3 minimum.

Comment: In documentation link that you have provided I found EXTRA_HTML_TEXT: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_HTML_TEXT but it is not working.

Comment: Acceptable solution to my problem could be sending HTML as attachment. So I tried again to use EXTRA_STREAM with file from sdcard and it works but I can't make it work with HTML from string. This is how I try to do it: intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Html.fromHtml(html)); Is it correct?