# Make text bold, italic, and bigger for email body in java

Tags: java, android, email

I send an E-mail with data retrieved throughout my application like such:

```
String body = formatEmailBody();

Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("message/rfc822");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"}); // Set receipient here
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , body);
try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Where `formatEmailBody` simply creates a `String` to be send as body of my email.

But a simple string is boring, how may I add bold / italic / bigger text?

I have tried the following to no success:

```
Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder()
            .append("<p><b>Some Content</b></p>")
            .append("<small><p>More content</p></small>")
            .toString()));
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the content-type of the message to "text/html"

Comment: I have, and the text does not take into account the tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I send mail from my app with underline or bold text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21807679/how-can-i-send-mail-from-my-app-with-underline-or-bold-text)

Comment: did you checked to add inline css ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look into [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), especially the section "Constants", where you see :

> EXTRA_HTML_TEXT : 
>   A constant String that is associated with the Intent, used with ACTION_SEND to supply an alternative to EXTRA_TEXT as HTML formatted text.

But please note [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_HTML_TEXT) :

> A constant String that is associated with the Intent, used with ACTION_SEND to supply an alternative to EXTRA_TEXT as HTML formatted text. Note that you must also supply EXTRA_TEXT.

So something like the below should improve the odds of the html content being displayed correctly :-

```
i.setType("text/html");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT, htmlText);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(htmlText));
```

Comment: And should I pass a String containing the desired tags or should I keep the format showed in the second code snippet when using this constant? It does not seem to work with a simple String as it throws an IllegalArgumentException, and the HTML format gives me an empty body.

Comment: EXTRA_HTML_TEXT also needs an EXTRA_TEXT to be supplied with some TEXT content ... try my updated answer ...

Comment: Only the non-Html text is displayed in the body

Comment: try setting type to text/html instead.

Comment: The HTML text is still not appearing

Comment: Look at this rather detailed code : http://code4reference.com/2012/08/copy-paste-intent-html-android/  ... especiall the function with the signature "public void sendHtmlIntent(View view) "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133546/discussion-between-addy-and-christopher-k).